# issue in $scope.$emit and $scope.$on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

when i'm adding new thing to selection list its work same time without refresh page but this is not happen when remove option for this need to refresh page to get relevant data list.

```
//This event call when add and remove 

     $scope.$emit("UserSetting_Update",true);


// add a module to the library

     $scope.$on('UserSetting_Update', function (event, data) {
            console.log('UserSetting recived:', data);
            $scope.getControlData();
        });







   // save CategoryItem

    console.log("save obj"+obj);
    client.onComplete(function (data) {

        $rootScope.Usertoolbox = obj;
        $scope.$emit("UserSetting_Update",true);
        $scope.showMessage('Saved your changes');
    });
    client.onError(function (data) { 
    $scope.showMessage('There was an error storing your changes');
});
    client.insert([obj], {
        KeyProperty: "UserID"
    });
```

Comment: Is your `console.log('userSetting received:', data);` appearing in the console?

Comment: yes it's print like this  UserSetting recived: true and database also update with new data set but changers doesn't appear on web until refresh

Comment: So the console.log is firing, but the UI doesn't update with the new data? Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: yes correct changers doesn't appear

Comment: can you try applying $scope.$apply() where you think the UI is not getting triggered?

Comment: I think you need to show some more code here. Please add tha controller which does the $emit and the controller which observse the $on

Comment: @Lakmi I would guess that in the code where you do the `$emit`, you are calling it from outside of Angular. Like @Marcus H said, you should try adding a `$scope.$applyAsync()` after your `console.log`. That should help fix it. But without more code, I can't say for sure.

Comment: $emit and $on working properly and data save and retrieve also working well but UI side doesn't refresh this is happen only for remove

Comment: actually now i'm confuse because remove and add call same methods. I'll put same code here.